# how to make textbox text will not disappear on button click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have TextBox and button1 on my asp.net webform.

I want when I click button1 then the text on the TextBox will remain the same as it is. It will not disappear, on button click event.

I want vb.net code to do this

Comment: Do you have a sample code that is not doing what you want?

Comment: -1: it wont disappear by default for asp.net webforms. have you done anything on ViewState? please be more specific.

Comment: Make sure you are using asp.net TextBox and not normal html text input. The former will retain value upon postback while the latter will lose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have ViewState enabled - it is enabled by default but it is possible that you have disabled it (either for the TextBox, or possibly for the entire page).